# pubnub api callback method error does not override method from its superclass

Tags: java, android

I am using pubnub api for a chat feature in my android app and code for `subscribe()` goes something like this

```
public void subscribe() {

        try {
            pubnub.subscribe(channel, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void connectCallback(String channel,
                                             Object message) {
                    notifyUser("SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:"
                            + channel
                            + " : "
                            + message.getClass()
                            + " : "
                            + message.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:" + message.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void disconnectCallback(String channel,
                                               Object message) {
                    notifyUser("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:"
                            + channel
                            + " : "
                            + message.getClass()
                            + " : "
                            + message.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG,"SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + message.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void reconnectCallback(String channel,
                                              Object message) {
                    notifyUser("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:"
                            + channel
                            + " : "
                            + message.getClass()
                            + " : "
                            + message.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG,"SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + message.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void successCallback(String channel,
                                            Object message) {
                    notifyUser("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                            + message.getClass() + " : "
                            + message.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG,"SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + message.toString());
                }


                @Override
                public void errorCallback(String channel,
                                          PubnubError error) {
                    notifyUser("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel "
                            + channel + " : "
                            + error.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + error.toString());
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

but I am getting the error for the overridden methods that `method does not override method from its superclass` or `method successcallback() is never used` ?? Can someone please explain these errors and how to remove them ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Error was occuring due to the wrong import of callback.In order to make these api's work we need to import the callback class provided by pubnub "com.pubnub.api.Callback" .